# Prevent video reloading when restarts

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I am trying to protect my uploaded videos from download. In fact, it works with an available URL only one to two seconds after the page is loaded.

But when the video is finished and you press play again, or when you put the timer back to 0, the player re-interrogates the URL of the video. Is there a way to prevent this reloading?

My player has no particularity, and the response of the video seems ok for me :

```html
<!-- Video player -->
<video preload="auto" muted controlsList="nodownload" poster="/uploads/images/movies/super-video.png">
    <source src="/src-teaser/mp4/1412042354243334_super-video_5952945345d78a81e97e57" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="/src-teaser/webm/1412042354243334_super-video_5952945345d78a81e97e57" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

```php
// Video response from Symfony 4 Controller
return new Response(file_get_contents($fileFullName), Response::HTTP_OK, [
    'Content-Disposition' => 'inline',
    'Content-Type'        => 'video/' . $type,
]);
```

Comment: Only way to protect data on the internet is to not put it there.

Comment: @mplungjan I know. But I can at least try to complicate the task.

Comment: the best solution would be a server side solution - have a url play-video?id=1&code=some unique code that you write in cookie or something When request goes to server server looks at unique code and determines if it has ever played you that video before. if it has it returns a short no no video, otherwise it streams the correct video.

Answer (score 0):

you could set and update a cookie while the video is playing:

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video");
video.currentTime = time;
video.ontimeupdate = function() {
  document.cookie = "time="+video.currentTime;
};
```

```html
<video width="200" height="100" id="video" controls>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<?php "echo("<script> var time = '$_COOKIE["time"]';<script>) ?>
```